# How to write testable controllers with private methods in AngularJs?

Tags: testing, angularjs, tdd

Alright, so I have been stumbling upon some issue for a long time and I would like to hear an opinion from the rest of community.

First, let's look at some abstract controller.

```
function Ctrl($scope, anyService) {

   $scope.field = "field";
   $scope.whenClicked = function() {
      util();
   };

   function util() {
      anyService.doSmth();
   }

}
```

Clearly we have here:

- regular scaffold for controller with `$scope` and some service injected
- some field and function attached to the scope
- private method `util()`

Now, I'd like to cover this class in unit tests (Jasmine). However, the problem is that I want to verify that when I click (call `whenClicked()`) some item that the `util()` method will be called. I don't know how to do that, since in Jasmine tests I'm always getting errors that either the mock for `util()` hasn't been defined or was not called.

**Note: I'm not trying to fix this particular example, I'm asking about testing such code pattern in general. So please don't tell me "what is exact error". I'm asking how to do that, not how to fix this.**

I have been trying a number of ways around this:

- obviously I cannot use `$scope` in my unit tests as I don't have this function attached to this object (it usually ends with message `Expected spy but got undefined` or similar)
- I tried attaching those functions to the controller object via `Ctrl.util = util;` and then verifying mocks like `Ctrl.util = jasmine.createSpy()` but in this case `Ctrl.util` is not being called so tests fail
- I tried to change `util()` to be attached to `this` object and mocking `Ctrl.util` again, with no luck

Well, I cannot find my way around this, I would expect some help from JS ninjas, a working fiddle would be perfect.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Namespacing it on the scope is pollution.  What you want to do is extract that logic into a separate function which is then injected into your Controller.  i.e.

```
function Ctrl($scope, util) {

   $scope.field = "field";
   $scope.whenClicked = function() {
      util();
   };
}

angular.module("foo", [])
       .service("anyService", function(...){...})
       .factory("util", function(anyService) {
              return function() {
                     anyService.doSmth();
              };
       });
```

Now you can unit test with mocks your Ctrl **as well as** "util".

Comment: As a clarification, I think that any piece of encapsulated logic you have should be injected, and your controller should **only** be responsible for assembling these injected logical actors with the scope variable for delivery to the template.

Comment: Sounds good, but sometimes the thing we want to test is as simple as: `if($scope.flag) service.a(); else service.b();`. It doesn't feel very natural to extract some component just for this one. However I get your point and I think after all this is a valid approach.

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman If the code you extracted into the private method is too simple to extract it into a separate mockable service, why not just ignore the internal code partitioning of `Ctrl` and verify this logic directly? I.e., in your example, instead of verifying the call to `util()` you rather verify the call to `anyService.doSmth()` (and any other service calls that might be in `util()`).

Comment: @Abbondanza is correct.  If the util should be separated because of logical concerns, it should be broken into a separate factory.  But it should not be separated out just to simplify testing.  See my answer for how to do this.

Answer (score 41):

The controller function you provided will be used by Angular as a constructor; at some point it will be called with `new` to create the actual controller instance. If you really need to have functions in your controller object that are not exposed to the $scope but are available for spying/stubbing/mocking you could attach them to `this`.

```
function Ctrl($scope, anyService) {

  $scope.field = "field";
  $scope.whenClicked = function() {
    util();
  };

  this.util = function() {
    anyService.doSmth();
  }
}
```

When you now call `var ctrl = new Ctrl(...)` or use the Angular `$controller` service to retrieve the `Ctrl` instance, the object returned will contain the `util` function.

You can see this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/yianisn/8P9Mv/

Comment: +1 I believe this is the way to go for small functions that are only used by a single controller that you don't want exposed to the scope.

Comment: ...until ControllerAs came along. Now what?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart what's wrong with controllerAs? `this.util` is perfect for mocking purpose, no? What is the issue?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart with controller as , adding to this will add to scope right ?

Comment: @Ezeewei, adding a function to `this` makes it available in views, which defeats the purpose of making it private.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to chime in with a different approach.  You shouldn't be testing private methods. That's why they are private - it's an implementation detail that is irrelevant for the usage.

For example, what if you realize that util was used in several places but now, based on other code refactoring, it's only called in this one place.  Why have an extra function call? Just include `anyService.doSmith()` inside you `$scope.whenClicked()` With the suggestions above, assuming you are testing that `util()` is called, your tests will break even though you haven't changed the functionality of the program.  One of the main values of unit testing is to simplify refactoring without breaking things, so if you didn't break things, the test shouldn't fail.

What you need to do is ensure that when `$scope.whenClicked` is called, `anyService.doSmth()` is also called.  You just need:

```
spyOn(anyService,'doSmith')
scope.whenClicked();
expect(anyService.doSmith).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: downvoter - please explain.  If the claim is that I didn't answer the question -  it's not true. I explained that to test private methods, you should test the required effects - not that a particular method was called.

Comment: yea hate the down vote without even explaining it :) mandatory explanation should for all downvotes :)

Comment: I don't see how testing whether `anyService.doSmith()` was called is any different than testing whether `util()` was called. They are both implementation details of your class. The only difference is one is an outside dependency and one is not. Yes, creating unit tests that depend on implementation details is brittle, but that's unit testing for you.

Comment: The difference is that `anyService.doSmth()` is an important function whereas `util()` isn't - it's just a wrapper/helper function.  I need to insure the doSmth function is called so I test for that.  This example doesn't illustrate why it makes a difference - but the idea is that doSmth is the function that is actually doing something - util is helping me organize my code.  If I had multiple events with different actions and helper functions to organize which events had which actions - the helper functions are irrelevant - just what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding an answer containing my current approach, hoping to get some comments and perhaps sparkle discussion about whether or not this is a good solution.

We are attaching private functions to the controller function (thus making them public, which enables mocking). To avoid having to repeat controller name all the times and making syntax more appealing, we are creating `self` object which holds reference to controller function. So it becomes:

```
function Ctrl($scope, anyService) {

   $scope.field = "field";
   $scope.whenClicked = function() {
      self.util();
   };

   var self = Ctrl; // For the sake of syntax simplicity only

   self.util = function() {
      anyService.doSmth();
   };

}
```

and then in unit tests now we can use:

```
Ctrl.util = jasmine.createSpy("util()");
expect(Ctrl.util).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I still don't like this very much, but I think this is the simplest way of doing this. I'm hoping someone will find better approach.

Comment: (biased) but I think adding the layer of nesting this under a "private namespace" makes the intent clearer - wether on $scope or on the controller class itself.

Comment: Yes, I'll agree. I only don't want to attach anything to the `$scope` as we have implemented project wide rule, that only objects that NEEDS to be evaluated during Angular's digest cycle can be attached to it. I'll agree, your solution is easier to manage.