# Testing named function within a Controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

A newbie Jasmine/Angular question.

I have a named function within a controller like so:

```
.controller( 'DummyCtrl', function DummyCtrl($scope){
   var doSomething = function() {
      return "blah";
   };
})
```

I need to test this function, and am trying to by calling the following Jasmine spec:

```
describe ('myApp', function(){
  var $scope, $controller;
  var DummyCtrl;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  describe('controllers', function(){
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope){
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      DummyCtrl = $controller('DummyCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
    }));

    describe( 'DummyCtrl', function(){
            var blah;

            beforeEach(function(){
                blah = DummyCtrl.doSomething();
            });

            it('should do something', function(){
                expect(blah).toContain("blah");
            });
    });
  });
});
```

Instead of things working out, I result in the following error: `TypeError: Object #<DummyCtrl> has no method 'doSomething'`.  I'm assuming this is something super simple that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a sense, using functions like that is private, and cannot be accessed from outside the function.  Take a look at this link: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Essentially what is said is that have a function/object in javascript, anything with a `this.` prefix is public, and anything with a `var` prefix is private.

For Angular, you can definitely have private variables and functions, if not just to lessen the memory usage of the `$scope` variable.  Private functions should be called by your `$scope` objects to get values to be displayed/used by the user.  Try changing it to this:

```
.controller( 'DummyCtrl', function DummyCtrl($scope){
   var doSomething = function() {
      return "blah";
   };
   $scope.something=doSomething();
})
```

And then testing the private function with:

```
describe( 'DummyCtrl', function(){
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = new DummyCtrl(scope);
    it('should do something', function(){
        expect(scope.something).toMatch('blah');
    });
});
```

Comment: that did the trick.  I was hoping I could call these private functions to streamline some unit tests (on $scope functions that call these methods). But I'm sure I can figure out a way to do it using what calls them.

Answer (score 18):

The `function DummyCtrl` you are providing for the controller registration will be used by Angular as a constructor. If you need the controller instance to expose the `function doSomething` without attaching it to the `$scope`, you should attach it to `this`.

Try changing

```
var something = function(...
```

to

```
this.something = function(...
```

and your test should work.

You can see this approach here: http://jsfiddle.net/yianisn/8P9Mv/. Also have a look at this  SO question: [How to write testable controllers with private methods in AngularJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15966989/1869460)

Comment: this should be marked as the answer. The other one doesn't do the problem fully.