# How to make AngularJS "private" methods testable?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have AngularJS service. Example:

```
module.service('myService', function () {
  var privateFoo = function () {
    console.log('I am public foo');
  }, 
  self = this;

  self.publicFoo = function () {
    console.log('I am public foo');
  };
});
```

Testing of this service:

```
it('test service', function () {
  expect(myService.publicFoo).toBeDefined(); // ok
  expect(myService.privateFoo).toBeDefined(); // not defined
});
```

Works like a charm. As expected.

The problem is I want to test private methods too. Why I need this?

Imagine, that `privateFoo` use/change some private object. I have `publicFoo`. There is a call to `privateFoo` in `publicFoo`. I want to unit test `publicFoo`. To do this, I need to mock all dependencies of `publicFoo` and all objects from functions which are called from `publicFoo` i.e. `privateFoo`.

Example of such service:

```
module.service('myService', function (privateDep) {
  var privateFoo = function () {
    privateDep.get('123');
  },
  self = this;

  self.publicFoo = function () {
    privateFoo();
    return 5;
  };
});
```

Test of publicFoo:

```
it('test publicFoo', function () {
  expect(myService.publicFoo()).toEqual(5); // fail, privateDep.get trying to get get of undefined
});
```

So, I need to mock privateDep to test publciFoo.

Actually, I want something like (just example, it is not working, because privateFoo is private :) ):

```
it('test publicFoo', function () {
  spyOn(service, 'privateFoo');
  expect(myService.publicFoo()).toEqual(5); // fail, privateDep.get trying to get get of undefined
  expect(service.privateFoo).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It will be possible if I will make private methods public, but, for example, with some prefix, like `_`. Like this: `self._privateFoo`. `_` prefix will show API users, that method is private and they must not use it.

How to make methods really private and testable in AngularJS service? Good solve for controllers (with $scope) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966989/how-to-write-testable-controllers-with-private-methods-in-angularjs) (well, methods are not really private, but at least they are in other scope and controller code looks pretty good.

Comment: Why do you want to test private methods? You should be testing the resulting state/return value of the public methods, i.e. the _behaviour_ of the component, not its internal structure

Comment: I agree with @Rhumborl but a possible solution is to define the service with the provider recipe, checking some initialize properties like "testContext" and if true you could publish private methods on $scope

Comment: Well, it is one of point of view. It is good reason. But it is unit tests. Unit = functions. For testing behaviour we should use integration tests, not units. Actually, when I created some service half year ago, I maked private methods and my unit tests really tests behaviour of components. Now I maked some minor fixes and I need to change refactor all unit tests now (~50). Well, yes. Behaviour changed, so it is reason to change units: mocks and tests. But it is hard to maintain all of this tests all time. Thats why I have this question.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to mock all dependencies of your service with $provide:

```
var privateDep = jasmine.createSpyObj('privateDep', ['get']);

beforeEach(function() {
  module('module name', function($provide) {
    $provive.value('privateDep', privateDep);
  });
});
```

This allows you to spy on dependencies when testing public methods of your service:

```
it('test publicFoo', function () {
  expect(myService.publicFoo()).toEqual(5);
  expect(privateDep.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(123);
});
```

Private methods will never be testable. This is not a problem because all logic of private methods is exposed via public methods and you can test those.

However if you have complicated logic in your private method you might consider extracting it to separate service and unit testing the new service separately.

Comment: It is not answer. I said that I need mock all objects. And it is not good, because it is hard to maintain units after. I have to configure big deps for each test. For each.

Answer (score 0):

Private code is inherently untestable but you can reduce the amount you have to triviality by writing as much logic as possible in pure, stateless functions.  Extract your stateless logic into separate abstract components to be tested separately, and then just use/compose them in your private functions.  Or, if there's no value in sharing such code, just leave it alone.

A unit is *not* equivalent to a function.  A modern, functionally-written js module or component may consist of 20 private and mostly trivial functions defined in 30 lines total, yet expose only 2 public functions.  A *unit* is something that can be used by something else and is thus defined by its interface, not its contents.  Conversely, a public function exclusively using its own personal private functions is not an interface, but merely an implementation detail.

Attempting to codify the internal structure and operation of your implementations only serves to make your entire architecture much more brittle while inflating the cost of unit testing.  After all, the very point of having interfaces is to create loose coupling and make implementations replaceable, which is why interfaces should be simple, lightweight, narrow in scope, *and connected via implementation to relatively few others*.

When testing is hard, it's usually an indication of poor system design, not of problems with the testing approach.  Respect the *value* of privacy and its aid in producing black boxes whose guts *don't matter*.